# Partial application doesn't work in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, currying

This function works as expected:

```js
const leftCharTrim = (c, s) => s.charAt(0) === c ? leftCharTrim(c, s.slice(1)) : s
console.log(leftCharTrim('a', 'abc'))
```

But the curried version doesn't work:

```js
const leftCharTrim = c => s => s.charAt(0) === c ? leftCharTrim(c, s.slice(1)) : s
const leftTrim = leftCharTrim('a') // partially applied
console.log(leftTrim('abc'))
```

Since `leftCharTrim` has received its first argument I expect `leftTrim` to be a function waiting for the second parameter and upon receiving it returns the result but calling `leftTrim` with second parameter returns a function. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `leftCharTrim` with the letter again and then with the second parameter.

```js
const leftCharTrim = c => s => s.charAt(0) === c ? leftCharTrim(c)(s.slice(1)) : s
//                                                             ^^^
const leftTrim = leftCharTrim('a') // partially applied
console.log(leftTrim('abc'))
```

Comment: Thanks. forgot to change the recursive part calling syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In the curried version, you're calling `leftCharTrim` with two arguments, but it takes only one and returns another function. You'd need to call that function as well. Or just call the partially applied function:

```
const leftCharTrim = c => {
  const trimC = s => s.charAt(0) === c ? trimC(s.slice(1)) : s
  return trimC;
};
const leftTrim = leftCharTrim('a') // partially applied
console.log(leftTrim('abc'))
```